# Abrir aquivos html,css e outros com comandos no terminal (LinuxMint) para o Browser

Tags: linux, terminal

Bom dia, Tarde, Noite, Senhores.

Por favor, sou iniciante em Linux, logo estou com pequenos impasses que diminuem minha produção, poderia alguém por favor me ensinar ou mostrar nos comentarios abaixo, como faço para abrir um arquivo html, css, e outros até pelo terminal para o browser?

Exemplo: Lembro bem que no Windows o comando é:
`start hello.html`

e no Mac é: `open hello.html`

Qual seria o comando para fazer o mesmo no LinuxMint?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda. Espero poder contribuir um dia.

PS: Utilizo o VSCode para programar.

Comment: Tenta ```xdg-open hello.html```

Comment: Sim, isso funcionou agradeço a ajuda.